# Add data with another view on app objective c

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I am trying to write  a project but with out success i need help:

in the first view i have `UITableView`  with a + on the navigator bar than after i push on him

I open a another view there  i want to add a first name and after then i  click "Done"  i want the name i wrote in the textfield will appears on the first view

and thats is my problem the name are not appears in the first view and i have not bug or error .

what can be missing in my project all the button are connected.

I need some help please.

Comment: you need to show some code, then only we can help.

Comment: How are you attempting to return the name to your first view?

Comment: Can you show some code?  It's not clear what you're doing or not doing here.

Comment: Can you tell us how you set up your delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not showing code, I have to have a pretty general description here.  With a button in the nab bar (which is what I think you're talking about) the button calls an action method.  Your action method is what moves you to the second view.

Even if your button is "wired up" correctly in your xib file, your action method may not be doing the right thing.  I'd try setting a breakpoint in your action method to 1) see if it gets called and 2) step through to see if you're creating a new view and pushing it on the UINavigationController's stack.

Comment: ok thank u ,now what code i need to sharing on my facbook i saw many tutorial and none of them not help me